# How do MariaDB and MySQL differ in character set handling?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, character-set, utf-8

In MySQL/MariaDB, I set the connection character set to UTF-8:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';
SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4';
```

There are some tables with a latin1_swedish_ci collation and latin1 encoded data in them. SELECTing from them gives me correct UTF-8 data.

When I once incorporated SET NAMES, SET CHARACTER SET in my program startup code, I assumed that I could give UTF-8 encoded data in INSERT strings to the MySQL server and it would convert it according to the table/column collation. That assumption came from me testing locally with MariaDB, where it worked. Then on the production site with MySQL: The UTF-8 data would not be converted to latin1 but saved as UTF-8 in Latin1 column. To fix that, I always encode values explicitly to latin1 when INSERTing into latin1 table.

Now, I revisited some code that did not SET NAMES, SET CHARACTER SET. I changed it to SET it. Now the MariaDB/MySQL difference strikes again. What is the difference between MariaDB and MySQL character set handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL and MariaDB handle character sets the same.  However...  Different *versions* of *MySQL* have different *defaults*.  Ditto for MariaDB.

`SET NAMES` declares what encoding is in the client.  This is independent of the `CHARACTER SET` on a column or table.  (There are, of course, characters that are not representable in latin1, so there can be conversion problems.)  As you say, the conversion occurs on `INSERT` or `SELECT`.

To further pursue this, please tell us what client you are using, what connection parameters were used, any SETs performed, and what happened.

For diagnosing what is stored, use `SELECT col, HEX(col)...`.  [More details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38363567/1766831).